# Log4j with writing in different files

Tags: java, log4j

hiho guys i want to ask you for the best practice (according to you) for writing a log in different files, for example i want info severity to be logged in info.log, debug severity in debug.log and so on... and no i dont want to use different Logger for each severity

Comment: Are you asking how to do this, or whether or not it's a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had an application that used to do this (separate log files per severity), and it ended up providing us no value.

All it ends up doing is A) complicating your debugging efforts, and B) taking up disk space.

Logging all severities to the same file is more convenient and easier to work with.

Comment: Worth mentioning there are log _viewers_ that can give you this effect while loading the entire log file. (If it's a small enough file; otherwise, there is always sed.)